# Which Powerlifting federations and hence competitions comply with WADA's anti-doping policies?

Tags: rules, doping, powerlifting

Rumoured that not all Powerlifting federations are under WADA that means that they do not comply with anti-doping policies. So some competitions allow the usage of dopings while others not. So

**Which powerlifiting competions comply with WADA's anti-doping policies?**

Answer (score 2):

The wordrecord [news](http://m.iltalehti.fi/fitnessvoimailu/2016051821587154_bs.shtml) meantions that IPF to be the only Powerlifting federation that complies with WADA's anti-doping policies:

> *"When a National Federation has received an Adverse Analytical Finding on one of its Athletes it shall report the following information to the IPF and **WADA within fourteen (14) days of the process described in Article 7.1**: the Athlete’s name, country, sport and discipline within the sport, whether the test was In-Competition or Out-of- Competition, the date of Sample collection and the analytical result reported by the laboratory."* [Their anti-doping site.](http://www.powerlifting-ipf.com/anti-doping.html)

and IPF website is in [International Powerlifting Federation](http://www.powerlifting-ipf.com/) and the [Prohibited List](http://www.powerlifting-ipf.com/fileadmin/ipf/data/anti-doping/wada-2016-prohibited-list-en.pdf).

**IPF and Exemptions forms in the case of needed medications**

Please note that if you are asthmatic, you need to file TUA 30 days before the competition by [this](http://www.powerlifting-ipf.com/fileadmin/ipf/data/anti-doping/IPF_WHAT_IS_DOPING_qaa_v_5.pdf)

> *"Wherean athlete needs to use beta 2 agonists as a treatment for asthma he/she needs a   TUE in advance (TUE application should be submitted no later than 30 days before the Athlete needs the   approval, for instance an Event)"*

and medications such as Glucocorticosteroids are prohibited so

1. Therapeutic Use Exemption (TUE application)
2. International Standard for 
   Therapeutic Use Exemptions (ISTUE)
3. Declaration of Use (DOU application)

**Supplements contaminated with steroids**

Notice that many commercially available supplements nowadays can be contaminated with prohibited steroids and may not manufactured in clean environments

> *"From the anti-doping perspective, the danger with many commercial supplements is that they may be tainted with prohibited substances.  **Alarmingly high rates of such contamination have been documented in independent analyses of supplements** purchased over the counter in health food shops or the like."* [Q8](http://www.powerlifting-ipf.com/fileadmin/ipf/data/anti-doping/IPF_WHAT_IS_DOPING_qaa_v_5.pdf)

**IPF Competitions and Testing In Competitions and Outside Competitions**

There are rules governing things such as comebacks and stopping competitions because the OCT (Out of Competition Testing) random tests are going all the time. The athletes need to report locations with a software every day so that they are available for tests. ICT (In-Competition Testing) does not require this but to stop OCT, the athlete must do a report.

> *"If a retired athlete wishes to come back to competition he or she must give written notice of that to the IPF.  From the date that notification is received, **the athlete must wait 6 months before they can again compete and in that time they are subject to OCT.**"*